# How to change database settings for a deployed war file?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl

We have a WAR file that is deployed however we want to change the database settings. How do I get about doing that? I opened the WAR file in an IDE and there are like 2-3 places that have the database settings. What is the proper way of changing it?

Thank You

Comment: What's your application server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tomcat instance should be set up to provide a datasource through JNDI.

Comment: Could You provide more detailed information/source, please? Pascal refers to Tomcat's MySQL example, but there is some data duplication (db driver type, auth) in applcation's web.xml and in context. Why to write ithem twice?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is to use a datasource at the application level and to administer it at the application server level. Check the [MySQL DBCP Example](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example) in the Tomcat documentation.

Comment: Pascal, I am new at this so maybe am not getting it. All I want to do is change from one database to another. I un-tarred my war file and changed the database settings in the DataBase.properties file. I then made it a WAR file and tested it and it was still pulling data from the old database.

Comment: there is some data duplication (db driver type, auth) in applcation's web.xml and in context. Why to write it twice?